# node app.js command does not work in ubuntu terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

I am using ubuntu.
I installed nodejs.
i created a rest api using node.
app.js is the file which has the code.

```
   var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({extended : true}));

app.get('/', function(request,response){

    response.json({message:'hit'});
});
app.listen(7000);
```

I tried to test the code by executing "node app.js" in terminal.
But it does not work.
what wrong i am doing here.
[image]

Following is my package.json

```
   {
  "private": true,  
  "name": "rest api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Rest Api",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "repository": {
     "type": "git",
     "url": ""
   },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Markand Bhatt",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I tried to install all dependencies using "npm install" command.
But I dont see anything installing. Following is the terminal screen.

[image]

Comment: Hard to help you debug code if you havn't posted any code

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Assuming `app.js` is an Express app, did you forget to start the server with `.listen()`?

Comment: Even if there is any error, i should get it in terminal, right? I dont get any message. Thats the problem

Comment: May be there's no error. Are you sure,if  you are using console.log anywhere in script?

Comment: There is no console.log. added code snippet

Comment: That code works fine when I test it. You aren't hitting Ctrl+C when you don't see anything visible are you?

Comment: This works fine in Windows. Does not work in Ubuntu.

Comment: Do you have a package.json file? Did you install dependencies using `npm install`?

Comment: added package.json and terminal screen

Comment: Your code seems correct to me. Try to run `node -v`.